# Align an image horizontally relative to a mask

Tags: mask, alignment, sketch-app

When I place an image inside a mask, is there a way to align horizontally/vertically that image so it's right in the center of that mask without me having to drag it around within the mask to find the center?

Trying to figure this out and can't find anything on it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Before masking that image alight it with the proposed mask as you like and then clip it using your favorite masking way.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select the mask layer and the image layer in the layer panel on the left and then use the standard align tools.

[image: Mask and Image Layer Selected]

Aligning can be found under *Arrange > Align Objects > Horizontal/Vertical*
This function is also available at the top of the inspector on the right.

[image: Aligning tools]